# Why do I get the "Maximum function nesting level of 100 reached" error?

Tags: 8

On all Drupal 8 beta sites, I have this error:

> Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached

Is this a problem with Drupal 8 or my server? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably caused by xdebug. Increase nesting level in php.ini

`xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200`

Comment: Here's a link to the core issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2393531.

Comment: There are a few issues, that one was actually closed, there is one still open somewhere. I don't think we can get rid of this, twig seems to add a lot of nested calls. So the best way can probably do is make the answer easy to find so that people find it when they google for it.

Comment: I found that, in addition to increasing xdebug.max_nesting_level, disabling xdebug was also needed, to continue with the installation of Drupal 8.0.0-rc1.